# How to do Layer Priority with JPanels?

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm learning Java and recently wanted to make a mimic a text message system like iMessage. My main issue right now is that I don't understand or what to use when it comes to having a layer priority system with the labels and textlabels I create. My current code puts everything in a fixed position and I can't alter the size/position at all. What's a good approach in implenting a layer system but also giving me the freedom to adjust the sizes/positions of the labels?

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.util.PriorityQueue;

    
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.*;
    import javax.accessibility.*;


    public class ChatSystem {

        static JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChatBot");
        static JTextField chat_input = new JTextField(8);
        static JFrame chatPanel = new JFrame();
        static JTextArea ca = new JTextArea();
        static JLayeredPane layoutPriority = new JLayeredPane();
        
        public static String getTextFieldText() {
            return chat_input.getText();
        }

        static void createScrollingFrame() {

            JPanel layeredPane = new JPanel();
            layeredPane.setOpaque(false); // Make the JPanel transparent
            frame.setContentPane(layeredPane);
            layeredPane.add(chat_input, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
            // Set the preferred size for the JPanel
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 800)); // Adjust the size as needed
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
        
            JPanel leftFrame = new JPanel();
            leftFrame.setBackground(Color.decode("#7289da"));
            leftFrame.setBounds(220, 20, 350, 550);
        
            JPanel rightFrame = new JPanel();
            rightFrame.setBackground(Color.decode("#9B90B2"));
            rightFrame.setBounds(720, 20, 350, 550);
        
            layeredPane.add(rightFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
            layeredPane.add(leftFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        
            // UI Labels
            JLabel client = new JLabel();
            Font f3 = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 35);
            client.setFont(f3);
            client.setText("Amel!a");
            client.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            client.setBounds(125, 0, 350, 200);
        
            layeredPane.add(client, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

            // Chat input position (adjust as needed)
            chat_input.setBounds(820, 950, 950, 40);
            layeredPane.add(chat_input, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        }
        
        static void chatHandler() {
            //handles create the "chat bubbles" with the text

            //take input and add to scrolling frame
        
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            
            frame.add(layoutPriority);
            
            frame.setLayout(null); // Set the layout manager for the frame
            frame.setSize(12000, 1200);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#1e2124")); // set background color
            frame.setVisible(true);


            //text input
            chat_input.setBackground(Color.decode("#7289da"));
            chat_input.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            
            // Font setup
            Font f3 = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15);
            chat_input.setFont(f3);
            
            // Adjust the position and size of the chat input
            chat_input.setBounds(220, 650, 850, 40);
            
            JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
            bottomPanel.setLayout(null); // Set null layout for precise positioning
            bottomPanel.add(chat_input);
            
            frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
            //create chat box // connect action 
            createScrollingFrame();

        
            
            EventListeners eventListeners = new EventListeners();
            chat_input.addActionListener((ActionListener) eventListeners);


            
        }    
    }
```

I've tried messing with different layout managers but I always face the issue of either the priority system works but I can't change the size/position, or I can change the size/position but the items are invisible. In reference, I'm more experienced in game programming so creating a system for layering my UIs was a problem I've never had to face.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the _"[z-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order)"_, as in _"xyz"_.  Use the _[setComponentZOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component,int))_ method for the container of the _Component_.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... My main issue right now is that I don't understand or what to use when it comes to having a layer priority system with the labels and textlabels I create. ... What's a good approach in implenting a layer system but also giving me the freedom to adjust the sizes/positions of the labels? ..."*

What you are referring to is typically called a *"[z-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order)"*; as in axes *x*, y, and *z*.

There is a method for this in the *[Container](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html)* class.

*[Container#setComponentZOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component,int))*,

> ***setComponentZOrder***
>
> ... Moves the specified component to the specified z-order index in the container. The z-order determines the order that components are painted; the component with the highest z-order paints first and the component with the lowest z-order paints last. Where components overlap, the component with the lower z-order paints over the component with the higher z-order. ...

More conveniently, you could use the *[JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)* component.

Here is the *Java* tutorial.
*[How to Use Layered Panes (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)*.
*[Java Tutorials Code Sample – LayeredPaneDemo.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LayeredPaneDemoProject/src/components/LayeredPaneDemo.java)*.

[image]

On a final note, in your code you should be calling *createScrollingFrame* prior to *frame.setVisible(true)*.