# Java Swing Adding a jPanel to a jPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to build a notification system using java and i am having an issue displaying my notification item using GlassPanePopup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naemk.png) Here is my notification and i am trying to add a new panel to it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3PwD.png)

This is the code for my graphics

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) grphcs.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(getBackground());
        int header = 10;
        AffineTransform tran = new AffineTransform();
        tran.translate(10, 5);
        // angle 45 degrees
        tran.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        Path2D p = new Path2D.Double(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 20, 20, 5, 5), tran);
        Area area = new Area(p);
        area.add(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, header, getWidth(), getHeight() - header, 10, 10)));
        g2.fill(area);
        g2.dispose();
        super.paintComponents(grphcs);
    }
```

here is my constructor

```
        setOpaque(false);
        JScrollBar sb = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
        sb.setOpaque(false);
        sb.setForeground(new Color(33, 140, 206));
        sb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(8, 8));
        scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scroll.setViewport(null);
        jPanel1.setLayout(new MigLayout("inset 0, fillx, wrap", "[fill]"));
        // tried to test notification system but doesnt work
        jPanel1.add(new notification_item("news", "Testing, testing, testing", "a second ago"));
        jPanel1.updateUI();
```

This is the jPanel i am trying to add to display each notification item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGL5P.png)

```
public notification_item(String name, String Description, String time ) {
        initComponents();
        jLabel1.setText(name);
        jLabel2.setText(Description);
        jLabel3.setText(time);
    }
```

and my constructor
Now my issue is that the jPanel doesnt display the jPanel i added to it so my notification doesnt display

Comment: Sounds like main panel has priority over the pop up. You can't show something on top if both have the same level of importance and it was there first.  Have a look at the reply on https://stackoverflow.com/a/77070748/13634116